# How to output first name using lambda in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to output a firstname from a list for every person which is younger than 15 years.

I have following code:

```
public class Main {

    static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.MM.yyyy");

    public static List<String> ReadFile (Path path) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/210211PersonenDaten.csv"));
    }

    public static List<Person> AddPersons (List<String> lines){
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.stream().forEach(line->{
            String [] splitter = line.split(",");
            personList.add(new Person(Integer.parseInt(splitter[0]),splitter[1],splitter[2], LocalDate.parse(splitter[3],formatter)));
        });
        return personList;
    }

    public static Stream<Person> FindCompulsorySchooling (List<Person> personList){
        return personList.stream().filter(x-> x.getBirthDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now().minusYears(15)));
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = ReadFile(Paths.get("src/210211PersonenDaten.csv"));

        List<Person> personList = AddPersons(lines);

        personList.forEach(System.out::println);

        //1
        FindCompulsorySchooling(personList).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

I've tried to access the list via personList.FirstName and give it out, but it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't exist at all.

```
FindCompulsorySchooling(personList).forEach(System.out::println(personList.FirstName));
```

Comment: Please show some sample input data and explain what is not working.  Also, please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes begin with an upper case letter; variables and methods begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` takes a consumer which is given each member of the list in turn, i.e. an object of type `Consumer<Person>`.

So if you write:

```
    private static class PrintFirstName implements Consumer<Person> {

        @Override
        public void accept(Person person) {
            System.out.println(person.FirstName);
        }
    }
```

inside your Main class, you can then say:

```
        FindCompulsorySchooling(personList).forEach(new PrintFirstName());
```

You can also do this with a lambda:

```
        FindCompulsorySchooling(personList).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.FirstName));
```

Which is equivalent to the `Consumer` above.

Comment: Thank for the answer, may I ask 1 more thing, what's the best way to calculate age from a whole list. I have dates when the people are born how could I get the age of each person ? Thanks

Comment: I have in Class called ´Person´ where I have declared Id,FirstName,SecondName and BirthDate

Comment: You can find the difference between a LocalDate and now in years with `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(p.getBirthDate().atStartOfDay(), LocalDateTime.now())`

Comment: Thanks, I solved it like this `public int getAge(){
        return Period.between(BirthDate,LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }`